# What does this graphic mean?

Tags: minecraft-bedrock-edition

In playing Minecraft on iPad, this animated graphic pops up randomly in the center of the screen… what does it mean?

[image: ipad]

It looks sort of like an animated audio waveform (the bars on the graphic go up and down like audio). I don’t think I’m doing anything to make it appear, it’s just random. And when it pops up, I can’t tap any buttons or get it to go away. I can move around though.

The only thing I can do is to force quit the game. 5-10 minutes later it pops up again.

What is it? What is causing it to appear? And how do I stop it/make it go away?

Comment: Does it come up in multiplayer only or also in single player? If it comes up in single player as well, it’s likely not your internet connection.

Comment: @DM01131 good point. Yes, I only play in single. Happens both in Creative and survival.

Comment: Weird. I can’t think what is causing this

Comment: That’s the loading animation in Minecraft Bedrock Edition. I have no clue why it keeps popping up, though.

Comment: Putting this in a comment because I don't have a full answer, but your error sounds somewhat similar to this guy's: https://www.reddit.com/r/MCPE/comments/b6jk37/world_loading_fails/ to me. He says he didn't get the error when he played with internet disabled on his device; do you happen to know if that's also the case for your issue?

Comment: It’s the loading icon that comes up when opening the settings isn’t it?

Answer (score 1):

Your game is loading something. Don't necessarily know what exactly, but it's loading something.

Answer (score 0):

its loading. this is the loading icon.

Answer (score -6):

I think it's your internet connection.

Comment: Could you clarify *why* it's your internet connection? In my experience an internet symbol is much smaller and simpler, this looks more like a volume level?

Comment: Thanks. My internet connection is rock solid and strong. I never have internet problems on that iPad (or any other device). But do we know definitively that that is what that graphic is indicating? Or is this just a guess?

Comment: Yea I guessed cause I don’t play Minecraft but since I played so many video games I just used my experience with games like urs